# Deleted java class still working in netbeans 8.1

Tags: java, ubuntu, netbeans

I am working on ubuntu with Netbeans 8.1 for java programming.
I created `testPageViewsRealTime` class in java and it has some error. Then I deleted it and create new class named as `ClickRawlogIngestionRealTime`. But when I running on new class `ClickRawlogIngestionRealTime` it throws an Exception

```
 testPageViewsRealTime Error: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

It's mean that the class `testPageViewsRealTime` still working. Can anyone tell me why and how can I get around this issue ? Thanks so much.

Comment: What code is running? It has a null reference but it is not possible to verify where and why of this without your code

Comment: You are doing right-click on project and select `Clean and Build` ?

Comment: sorry, I check it so much. And then I foud that in try catch I System.out.println(" testPageViewsRealTime Error: "+ex). It's so silly